# MVC4 form input with no selected file is deleting database image field content

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Need help as i'm new to web dev and MVC technology.

Problem details :
I have a view, called "Dossier", showing details of a person with image.
On loading the view, the image is shown correctly from database.
If i change any field in the form for example : name, and click the save button to submit the form, the image is sent empty, and this is overriding the database image field with null value.
Note that if i click on the image, the Open Dialog form is shown, and after selecting a valid image, this one is successfully uploaded to Database.

I'm confused as i'm looking for all similar posts since 3 days before posting here.

My Get and Post methods on the controller :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Dossier(string myPatientId)
    {
        Patient patient;

        using (var ctx = new MedikEntities())
        {
            patient = ctx.Patients.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PatientId == myPatientId);
        }

        // check if not null
        if (patient == null)
            return RedirectToAction("List");

        return View(patient);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Dossier(Patient patient, HttpPostedFileBase photo)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
            return View(patient);

        if (photo != null)
        {
            patient.ImageMimeType = photo.ContentType;
            patient.PatientPicture = new byte[photo.ContentLength];
            photo.InputStream.Read(patient.PatientPicture, 0, photo.ContentLength);
        }

        using (var ctx = new MedikEntities())
        {
            // register the patient
            ctx.Patients.Attach(patient);

            // set entity as changed
            ctx.Entry(patient).State = EntityState.Modified;

            // commit changes
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View(patient);
    }
```

View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Dossier", "Patient", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enregistrer" />
    </p>

    <div class="box box-info-male">
        <div>
            <p style="float: left;">
                <img class="photoPatient" 
                     src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Patient", new { Model.PatientId })" 
                     alt="@Model.PatientPicture"
                     id="myPhoto" 
                    style="cursor: pointer"
                    />
            </p>
            <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" style="display: none" />
```

And finally the GetImage method :

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(string patientId)
        {
            using (var ctx = new MedikEntities())
            {
                var patient = ctx.Patients.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PatientId == patientId);
                return patient != null ? File(patient.PatientPicture, patient.ImageMimeType) : null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where did you set the mime type?

Comment: It's in the database field also, same table. for information i just followed the SportsStore sample from the book : Pro ASP.NET MVC 4

Comment: Just double checking. Your code returns null if patient is null, have you verified what is being returned? And have you checked that the mime type is being sent down properly?

Comment: @MikeCheel, i used the debuger to follow the values posted. All fields are correctly posted to the model, only PatientPicture field is null...Also the MIME field posted to database is null

Comment: But are you returning an actual file or null AND when you look in the chrome debugger at what was brought down for the file what is the mime type?

Comment: How can i check this on chrome Debugger ?? is it under network tab ?

Comment: Open the debugger, select the network tab, refresh the page. Look for your resource under the type column.

Comment: So...
1. When PatientPicture has value in DB, it is show correctly via GET form with type : Image/Jpeg

2. When i click on picture to send new picture, POST send the correct type Image/Jpeg and it is correctly saved to the DB

3. When i reload the form, change another field without changing a new picture, the POST send the type application/octet-stream instead

4. When the form is loaded the GET shown an error status : 500 Internal Server error... and the type is text/html

Comment: It sounds like you are making progress in figuring this out then.

Comment: Yes, i know that my code is sending an empty file, i checked the filename on POST, i understand that and now i'm looking for a solution using jQuery to avoid sendig the null value for input file parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours and hours of debugging, i've finally found a solution to my problem.

Remember the code used to show the image :

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(string patientId)
    {
        using (var ctx = new MedikEntities())
        {
            var patient = ctx.Patients.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PatientId == patientId);
            return patient != null ? File(patient.PatientPicture, patient.ImageMimeType) : null;
        }
    }
```

The call of File(patient.PatientPicture, patient.ImageMimeType) is the problem. i've found that the Mime Type sent to the form is NULL in case of user do not select file. Then, my model set the picture field to Null also.

So as solution i've changed the second method parameter as following to force the Type to be image:

```
return patient != null ? File(patient.PatientPicture, "image/jpeg") : null;
```

After many tests, all cases are giving the right result, now if the user select a file, it is correctly loaded, shown on page and then saved to database. If the user load the form again, image is shown correctly, if any field is changed without selecting a new file for submit, the old picture is still there and database field for picture is not null.

May be someone can explain this to me in more details, i just followed my logic and got it